# Merging two spatial datasets based on both geometry intersection and year (try to create cell-year panel data, so basically 2 conditions) in R

Tags: r, merge, attribute-joins, sf, sp

I am trying to merge two datasets, both have geometry column (1st with polygons-cells and 2nd with points). Where i want the 2nd dataset (with the points) to be merged to the 1st dataset (with polygons) by both geographic intersection and matched year. So to get a panel data where each polygon (cell in my case) have multiple observations over time.

Ideally, I am looking for something like "merge" in base R:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x=c("condition 1", "condition 2"), by.y=c("condition 1", "condition 2")).
```

But I did not find the equivalent command of spatial objects (can `st_join` get multiple conditions?).

Comment: Check out this link https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-operations.html?q=join#spatial-joining for some examples on how to perform spatial joining, and examples of `st_join()`. If I understand your question properly, `st_join()` will be able to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an R guy, but this is really simple in SQL.  If you call SQL statements in your R script, or are comfortable converting SQL syntax to R:

```
SELECT * FROM df1 INNER JOIN df2 ON df1.year = df2.year and ST_INTERSECTS(df1.geom,df2.geom)
```

Otherwise, I would explore GeoPandas `sjoin`. This is a 2 part hack that first combines the two dataframes, then select the rows that have a matching year. Might be possible to do this in 1 line.

```
df3 = gpd.sjoin(df1, df2, how='inner')
df3.loc[df3['df1_year'] == df3['df2_year']]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but unfortunately the sql does not manage to read the spatial datasets (using sqldf package to read sql code in R).